# Use geom_smooth to create multiple lines from multiple criteria?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, line, point

I am trying to create multiple smooth lines based on criteria 1 with same linetype and assign different colours to each line based on criteria 2. I looked through various similar questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600824/how-to-apply-geom-smooth-for-every-group/40600861), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873060/using-ggplot2-in-r-creating-multiple-smoothed-fitted-lines?rq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272899/fitting-geom-smooth-to-multiple-categories-in-ggplot2)) in stackoverflow but they all worked on single criteria rather than two criteria. I tried different approaches but have not got the complete result. The different approaches and its result are as follows:

APPROACH I:

```
data(mtcars)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, colour = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth( aes(group = as.factor(carb)),method ="lm", se = F, fullrange = T, alpha = .15, linetype = "dashed") 
p
```

The result is: [image]

The colours to the points is correct and single linetype. However, number of lines and colour are wrong. I want lines to have red, blue or green colour based on "cyl" value.

APPROACH II:
The second approach I tried, gave me correct number of lines and colour but had different linetype for each line.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, colour = as.factor(cyl), linetype = as.factor(carb))) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth( method ="lm", se = F, fullrange = T, alpha = .15) 
p
```

[image]

APPROACH III:
In approach III, the results were similar to approach I.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, colour = as.factor(cyl), group = as.factor(carb), linetype = "dashed")) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth( method ="lm", se = F, fullrange = T, alpha = .15) 
p
```

[image]

In nutshell, Approach II gets me closest to my objective. Now, how to get single linetype in Approach II?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest next approach, formating linetypes:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
data(mtcars)
#Plot
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, colour = as.factor(cyl), linetype = as.factor(carb))) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth( method ="lm", se = F, fullrange = T, alpha = .15) 
p + scale_linetype_manual(values = rep('solid',length(unique(mtcars$carb))))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank You! Got it.

Comment: @Rahi Great! If you think this answer was helpful, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)